# Example of Quarkus Jwt in resteasy reactive

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-reactive

when i use

```
@Inject
JsonWebToken jwt;
```

in function that returning Uni, it always show this error

> Cannot call getIdentity() from the IO thread when lazy authentication is in use, as resolving the identity may block the thread. Instead you should inject the CurrentIdentityAssociation, call CurrentIdentityAssociation#getDeferredIdentity() and subscribe to the Uni.

is there any example how to use JWT in quarkus resteasy reactive ?

the error goes away if i use @Blocking in the function.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is 2 possibilities here.

If you have disabled proactive authentication, you could enable it back to get non blocking access to your token. See [quarkus proactive auth docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#proactive-authentication), it says :

> Note that if proactive authentication is in use accessing the SecurityIdentity is a blocking operation

**BUT**, the real solution IMHO would be to do as stacktrace suggest :

```java
// Inject this instead of your JsonWebToken
@Inject
CurrentIdentityAssociation identities;

...

// And retrieve your token this way
Uni<JsonWebToken> getJwt() { 
    return identities.getDeferredIdentity()
                     .onItem()
                     .transform(identity -> (JsonWebToken) identity.getPrincipal());
}
```

Comment: Hello @jacouille! I get an error from your code because this is an illegal cast `(JsonWebToken) identity.getPrincipal()`. Can you clarify? Thank you!

Comment: Hello @micha ! Please write a new question and link it to me so i can take a look

Comment: Thank you @jacouille! I created a new question here, please have a look! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73701617/how-to-access-jwt-in-quarkus-when-proactive-auth-is-disabled